# Очередь команд в консоли Linux

Tags: linux, shell

Предположим, что в данный момент в консоли **уже** выполняется какая-то команда. Она занимает продолжительное время. Я хотел бы выполнить одну или несколько команд после того, как завершится эта. Как это сделать?

Я знаю, что можно <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> и `bg`, но это не совсем то. Нужно не в бэкграунд отправить команду, а именно дождаться ее завершения.

Comment: Можно создать sh-скрипт, особенно, если команды выполняются часто.

Comment: @Дмитрий да, это можно, но мне интересна разовая ситуация. То есть команда уже выполняется, надо добавить новые.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

используйте не `bg` (*background*), а `fg` (*foreground*), после которой добавьте нужную команду (команды):

```
$ date; sleep 10
Fri Oct  2 10:45:04 MSK 2015
^Z
[1]+  Stopped                 sleep 10
$ fg; date
sleep 10
Fri Oct  2 10:45:14 MSK 2015
```

`fg` и последующую команду можно связать и условиями, например: `&&` или `||`.