# Команда освобождающая консоль от процесса

Tags: linux, консоль

Например запускаю: php -S localhost:8080, всё, консоль занята, нужно открывать новую. 
Но, есть команда которая позволит дальше работать в этом же окне.

Comment: Похожий вопрос задавал, может вам пригодиться: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/455272/181472

Comment: Плюсанул. [https://habrahabr.ru/post/105657/](нашел пост на хабре)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если процесс уже запущен, а нужна эта же консоль, можно усыпить процесс с помощью `Ctrl-Z`, а потом возобновить в фоне (background) с помощью команды `bg`.

Comment: я сразу не понял, как это работает. Но эта та команда, которую я когда-то видел в одной статье, которую забыл и решил спросить здесь!

Answer (score 7):

Можно использовать **&** - переводит процесс в `background`:

```
$ php -S localhost:8080 &
```

Можно использовать **screen** :

```
$ screen
new_screen> php -S localhost:8080
нажатие одновременно CTRL+A+D - возвращает нас в родительскую консоль
$ screen -r - обратное подключение к созданному screen-у
```

Дополнительная информация :

- https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-bash-s-job-control-to-manage-foreground-and-background-processes
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/76717/bash-launch-background-process-and-check-when-it-ends
- http://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/screen
- http://www.rootfront.com/article/10033021/2013-10-30/10-primerov-komandy-screen-dlja-upravlenija--linux-terminalom

Answer (score 1):

Для таких дел есть tmux.
`tmux new` создаем сессию, `tmux attach` переключаемся.

Comment: Можно просто `tmux`.